# Is it possible to make a csv file out of a non delineated list?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have over 100,000 pieces of data im working on and the issue is that it was written in a very non conducive format, pdf. I have no idea of how to separate the data. I'm using pandas and matplotlib to do some basic plotting on this data. I cannot figure out how to make a csv out of this.

For example:

```
Property 1
Data 1
Data 2 
Data 3
Property 2 
Data 4 
Data 5 
Data 6
```

I have tried using find and replace but do to there being no formatting I cannot figure it out, but i do not have the time to literally go through each piece of data and manually adding a comma.

I would hope to be able to plot each property as a column with each data piece being a cell.

Comment: Are you asking how to get text out of a PDF, or how to organize text data into a CSV file?

Comment: so you produced a textfile with the format you gave in the example? - exactly four lines for every data record? - then, yes, of course you can parse it automatically; if the lengths vary, then much harder

Comment: No that was just an example its varying lengths with each data point having a varying length, its about 10,000 points per property.

Answer (score 0):

1) You may be able to copy and paste the data into an excel file. You can then split the column by going into "Data" and then "Text to Column".

2) If you are already reading a dataframe in python and need to split one column into 2  - You could create additional columns in the dataframe from the original data.